# Create Custom block on Product View with form

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks, product-view-page

I'm trying to do a form and put this on Product View.
I did some fields and they are saving the results on DB, ok, everything is good. But, I need to insert this block there. 
Any thing that I help me?

Answer (score 1):

In your theme, you should extend catalog.xml and inside him put:

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="product.info">
        <block type="<your_class_block>" name="<your_name>" template="<your_template_file>"/>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

But, if you don't want product.info you can add a block inside `<catalog_product_view>`

```
<catalog_product_view>
        <block type="<your_class_block>" 
name="<your_name>" 
template="<your_template_file>"/>
</catalog_product_view>
```

then in your view.phtml you should put:

```
$this->getChildHtml('<your_name_or_alias_of_block');
```

Answer (score 0):

1. > app/design/frontend/{package}/{themename}/template/catalog/product/view/form            /my_custom_form.phtml

   ```
   //your form content here
   ```
2. > app/design/frontend/{package}/{themename}/layout/local.xml

   ```
   <catalog_product_view>
       <reference name="root">
           <block type="core/template" name="my.custom.form" template="catalog/product/view/form/my_custom_form.phtml"/>
       </reference>
   </catalog_product_view>
   ```
3. > app/design/frontend/{package}/{themename}/template/catalog/product/view.phtml

   ```
   <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml("my.custom.form"); ?>
   ```